# Wifi access points not showing up

Tags: wifi

I just installed debian buster and for some reason the wifi doesn't show any ap thats nearby. It says WiFi Unavailable at the top.. please help im really new to this environment[image: no networks found]

edit: i downloaded debian on a toshiba laptop,[image][image]

I finally fixed it! I had some missing firmwares and it worked perfectly when i installed them

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you tell us on which device you installed Debian buster? Can you show the output of `lspci` so that we understand what WiFi adapter is installed?

Comment: I remember skipping the "add network configuration" during the installation process of debian but i dont know if its because of that. Also thank you for the reply

Comment: Can you show the output of ```lsmod | grep 8723```

Comment: i tried doing "sudo iwlist scan" and for wlp2s0 it said "Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down"

Comment: Don't answer in the question, answer in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I almost gave up and tried to reinstall debian with my usb and i noticed it asked me to install two missing firmwares  and gave its name (in my case it was rtlwifi/rtl8723fw_b.bin and rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw) so i stopped the installation and went back to my debian, i installed the "firmware-realtek_20200918-1_all.deb" file on my phone from https://packages.debian.org/sid/firmware-realtek since i couldn't connect to internet on debian, i transferred the file to my debian through a usb from my phone and installed the the .deb file with the command "sudo dpkg -i realtek_20200918-1_all.deb" and rebooted my device once that was done i was able to connect to the internet  :)